# "Aspects in" vs. "Aspects of"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, difference

Is there any actual difference between "aspects in" and "aspects of", apart from their [frequency](http://%3Ciframe%20name=%22ngram_chart%22%20src=%22https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=aspects%20in%2Caspects%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caspects%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caspects%20of%3B%2Cc0%22%20width=900%20height=500%20marginwidth=0%20marginheight=0%20hspace=0%20vspace=0%20frameborder=0%20scrolling=no%3E%3C/iframe%3E)? As far as I can see, the comparatively rare "aspects in" occurs especially when followed by the name of a discipline (e.g. "aspects in astrology").

Comment: Can you use "aspects in" and aspects of" in example sentences?

Comment: @Jan well, "aspects of" is the regular expression ("aspects of an issue, a phenomenon" etc.), but I found also some occurrences of "aspects in" followed by a topic/science ("aspects in chemistry, geology" etc.). In other words, we all agree that one can say "aspects **of** the evolution of the Assyrian civilisation", but can one say "aspects **in** the evolution of the Assyrian civilisation" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/aspect): "Aspect means a part or feature of something."

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aspect): "Since *aspectus* in Latin means "looked at", an aspect of something is basically the direction from which it's looked at."

So, an aspect is a **part or characteristic of** something, depending from which viewpoint you look at it.

> A questionnaire dealing with fertility knowledge, attitudes, and
>   practices, and various aspects **of** health care was developed and
>   pre-tested. *([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/various-aspect))*
>
> In almost all aspects **of** life, the application of this process will
>   bring improvements. *([Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/aspects))*

Different English dictionaries almost exclusively present examples of "aspects of;" [Your Dictionary](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/aspects) mentions 323 examples of "aspects of" and no relevant example of "aspects in."

In the example "aspects in chemistry," the word "in" is not a part of the phrase "aspects in" but refers to different opinions that exist **in** this field. Or yet another angle: [Angular Momentum: Understanding Spatial Aspects in Chemistry and Physics](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Angular+Momentum%3A+Understanding+Spatial+Aspects+in+Chemistry+and+Physics-p-9780471858928). Again, in this case, "in" refers to how to understand "spatial aspects" "in the filed of chemistry or physics," so, again "in" is not the part of the phrase "aspects in."

The example of "aspects in" in: "Financial Aspects in Energy: A European Perspective" maybe comes from non-English authors or, again, just refers to different perspectives that "exist in" the field of energy in Europe.

In conclusion: As a phrase, it's always "aspects of," while "in" can follow "aspects" coincidentally as a part of the sentence structure.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, we talk about **aspects of** something - a science, an issue, a philosophy, a personality.

I would follow the word **aspects** with **in**, only if the word **in** were introducing a phrase, such as:

> There are several aspects, in this instance, that deserve further scrutiny.
>   The visual aspects, in general, are less than satisfactory.
>   These aspects, in the light of the accused's record, must be taken into account.

**Aspects in astrology** sounds wrong to me unless you have specified what aspects you are referring to, for example:

> There are aspects of prediction that we don't fully understand.
>   Yes, but these aspects (of prediction) in astrology are useful nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found quite a lot of occurrences of "aspects in+science" in Google Books, that's why I was wondering if it was acceptable. Actually, it seems also common the structure "adj+aspects in+topic": examples from Google Books titles include
"Future Aspects in Contraception", "Algorithmic Aspects in Information and Management", "Financial Aspects in Energy: A European Perspective" and so on. It seems that many of these books' authors are non-native speakers, though, so that could be an explanation.

Comment: More importantly: in the examples you cited "in" is not really introducing a phrase, but is part of a parenthetical expression ("in general", "in that case") which is fully detached from "aspects". I was asking about the viability of the construction "aspects in+something".

Comment: @Karl My answer is based on my experience. I haven't come across instances of the kind you quote although I can imagine their use in the sense of **direction**, as per the source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aspect